# How to change URL in flash game

Tags: flash, swfobject

I have no knowledge of how flash works. I was moving an old site flash game to a new site. The flash game works on the old site but does not work on the new site.

The game itself loads but is looking for an XML file by the name words.xml. I do have access to that file but the URL it is pointing to from the flash game is wrong and I can't seem to find out how can I change the URL. Please help!

I can provide with whatever details needed. I donot know how much is needed please do let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

The URL is most probably hard coded in the SWF and you can't natively change it unless you have the original construction file for the game, likely a *.FLA file, in which case you can open that, find the URL in there, replace it and re-export the SWF

Otherwise you could try [decompiling the SWF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597879/edit-the-action-script-in-swf-files) using one of various third party applications, but recompiling it might be difficult or impossible